# getting error in while installing react-lottie in react18

Tags: reactjs, macos, visual-studio-code

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
```

npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: mytestonmac@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14.7 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-lottie@1.2.3
npm ERR! node_modules/react-lottie
npm ERR!   react-lottie@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See /Users/apple/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/apple/.npm/_logs/2022-05-10T10_42_29_299Z-debug-0.log

Comment: react-lottie is no longer maintained, last commit is from 4 years ago, there's little chance that this library will work with recent react versions.

Comment: yeah got it solved this problem using lottie-web

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`--force` works, but might have some unexpected consequences. I added an override for now for it in my `package.json`:

```
"overrides":{
    "react-lottie": {
      "react": "^0.14.7 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" 
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

```
npm i react-lottie -force
```

You can use -force to install library doesn't support latest ReactJS yet

Answer (score 1):

React-lottie is no longer maintained I think. Use lottie-react - https://www.npmjs.com/package/lottie-react

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following command and no error

npm i lottie-react

Answer (score 0):

That one is outdated so I would suggest you try using lottie-web

`npm install lottie-web`
`yarn add lottie-web`

here is the documentation:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/lottie-web